# Grab just the first filename from a zip file stream?

Tags: bash, header, zip

I want to extract just the first filename from a remote zip archive without downloading the entire zip. In particular, I'm trying to get the build number of [dartium (link to zip file)](https://storage.googleapis.com/dartium-archive/continuous/dartium-lucid64.zip). Since the file is quite large, I don't want to download the entire thing.

If I download the entire thing, `unzip -l` reports the first file as being: `0  2013-04-07 12:18   dartium-lucid64-inc-21033.0/`. I want to get just this filename so I can parse out the `21033` portion as the build number.

I was doing this (total hack):

```
_url="https://storage.googleapis.com/dartium-archive/continuous/dartium-lucid64.zip"
curl -s $_url | head -c 256 | sed -n "s:.*dartium-lucid64-inc-\([0-9]\+\).*:\1:p"
```

It was working when I had my shell in ASCII mode, but I recently switched it to UTF-8 and it seems sed is now honoring that, which breaks my script.

I thought about hacking it by doing:

```
export LANG=
curl -s ...
```

But that seemed like an even bigger hack.

Is there a better way?

Comment: That's a pretty cool solution to get information about the file list without downloading the entire thing, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can set bytes range using curl.

Next, use "strings" to extract all strings from binary stream.

Add "q" after "p" to quit after find only first occurrence.

```
curl -s $_url -r0-256 | strings | sed -n "s:.*dartium-lucid64-inc-\([0-9]\+\).*:\1:p;q"
```

Or this:

```
curl -s $_url -r0-256 | strings | sed -n "/dartium-lucid64/{s:.*-\([^-]\+\)\/.*:\1:p;q}"
```

It must be a bit faster and more reliable. Also it extracts full version, including subversion (if you need it).